# How to get insertion order by looking at a B+ tree?

Tags: b-tree

I was trying to figure out how I can figure out the order of insertion of elements in a B+ tree just by looking at the final tree.

Are multiple insertion orders possible? If yes, how to find any one of them?

In simple Binary Trees, the insertion order is same as the preorder traversal.

Thank you.